# In a C program in Linux OS, how to check if a user has read permission on a file?

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions

The function would be something like this.

```
int GetFilePermission(char* pcUsername, char* pcFilePath)
{
    /*return TRUE if 'pcUsername' has read permission on file 'pcFilePath'.*/
}
```

I don't want to use stat(). Since it would be little bit long. I have to check file's permissions, it's owners and compare them in different combinations. Is there any short and simple way/trick of doing this?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512434/using-struct-stat

Comment: Check also related functions linked from the [`stat` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Comment: for a dozen helper functions, see the [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html)

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799053/check-for-writing-permissions-to-file-in-windows-linux

Comment: My program is running as a root. But I want to check whether a user (e.g. david) has a read permission on the file. fopen() returns the permissions w.r.t. to the calling process. And I can do it using stat(), but obviously it would be a little bit long. I thought there would be some very effective trick. Probably my thought was wrong.

Comment: Yes, curiously seems like there is no popular higher level approach. Like in the old joke "How Programmers Hunt Elephants":  C programmers refuse to buy rifles off the shelf, preferring to take steel rods and a mobile machine shop to Africa intending to build the perfect rifle for the job from scratch while everyone else bags the elephants.

Answer (score 1):

Using the access function we can get the user having a permission. See the man page of access.

`int access(const char *pathname, int mode);`

If you stat function, you getting all information about that file. In access we have these four only. `R_OK, W_OK, X_OK and F_OK.` Using this we can get easily. Return value is zero if success.

```
R_OK = read permission
W_OK = Write permission
X_OK = Execute permission
F_OK = file is existing.
```

Comment: My program is running as a root. But I want to check whether a user (e.g. david) has a read permission on the file. access() returns the permissions w.r.t. to the calling process.

Comment: @JatiA If the root is the owner of the file then check the other and group permission of that file. It can be done with the stat function.

Comment: If your program is running as root is easy to impersonate the user in question and just try to open the file while capturing exceptions (this EAFP approach is very portable).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `stat`

**Prototype for stat**

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
```

Comment: OP specifically said they don't want to use stat

Comment: @nerdguy Looks like they edited the question after the answer. You can see the history. In the original question there was no mention of it. They updated the question after 4 minutes from my answer. Sad!